# Python: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sleep'

Tags: python

I'm receiving a strange error when running my program? I'm not sure why it wont let me sleep.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Not an add minute at all.
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/test/odd.py", line 15, in <module>
    time.sleep(0.05)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sleep'
```

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import time
from random import random

odds = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59]

right_this_minute = datetime.today().minute

for i in range(0, 11):
    if right_this_minute in odds:
        print("This minute seems a little odd.")
    else:
        print("Not an add minute at all.")

    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 60))
```

Comment: `from time import time` is making `time` in your code the `time` function in the `time` module, not the module itself.  Do `import time` instead.

Comment: Using Spyder, with `import time` when calling `time.time()` I received the error `builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'time'` which was silly. However I previously tested `from time import time` and for some reason Spyder or Python didn't forget this import. I had to reset the kernel to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 16):

Change `from time import time` to `from time import sleep`

Then you can use sleep directly instead of time.sleep

Answer (score 4):

So I had the same awkward problem. I say awkward because a couple of days ago when I solved an exercise and used the following import statement: "from time import sleep", my code worked just fine when using `time.sleep(n)`. After a couple of days of adding code to the same .py file, my previously working function definition that used `time.sleep(n)` did not work anymore.

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sleep'
```

This is the error it threw at me. I did not change anything to the import statement used when I have initially imported sleep from the time module.

**Resolve:**
I ended up having to delete `time` from `time.sleep(n)` and used only `sleep(n)` as Agile_Eagle suggested. Thx for that! But why would it work initially and then crash with that error...?

```
from time import sleep
from time import *             #meaning from time import EVERYTHING
import time`
```

All of the above import methods work just fine for importing the time module/or for importing just "**sleep**" from the time module, but now I can only use `sleep(n)` instead of `time.sleep(n)` (as I did initially when I solved the exercise).

Answer (score 3):

snakecharmeb is right, and also, you need to import random rather than from random import random.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import random


odds = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59]

right_this_minute = datetime.today().minute

for i in range(0, 11):
    if right_this_minute in odds:
        print("This minute seems a little odd.")
    else:
        print("Not an add minute at all.")

    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 60))
```

Comment: Thank you, that's fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

you are importing wrong way "time" package...

```
import time
time.sleep(5) #sleeps for 5 seconds
```

That is all.

Answer (score 1):

You should write like this:

```
import time
```

you can see the [full doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep).